# Firestore/Vuejs: Can't delete from Firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a doc from Firestore, but I think it doens't get the document id.

When I click on the v-btn it don't get the id of the :key.

**Here I get the data from the Firestore database**

```
<v-row v-for="shopItems in shopItem" :key="shopItems.id">
    <v-col>
        <p>{{shopItems.product}}</p>
    </v-col>
    <v-col>
        <p>{{shopItems.catogorie}}</p>
    </v-col>
    <v-col>
        <p>{{shopItems.price}}</p>
    </v-col>
    <v-col>
        <v-btn @click="deleteItem(shopItems.id)">X</v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

**Vue js data()**

```
shopItem: [],
product: '',
catogorie: '',
price: '',
userId: '',
```

I got this from a other page (same project) what works but this function gives me only a error.

**Here is my Vue js methods**

```
methods: {
        deleteItem(doc) {
            db.collection("StoreCart").doc(doc).delete().then(function() {
                console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
                // location.reload()
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
            });
        }
    },
    created() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userId => {
            if(userId) {
                this.userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                db.collection("StoreCart").get().then((res) => {
                    res.docs.map((doc) => {
                        // console.log(doc.data().userId)
                        if(doc.data().userId == this.userId) {
                            this.product = doc.data().catogorie
                            this.catogorie = doc.data().catogorie
                            this.price = doc.data().price
                            this.shopItem.push({
                                product: doc.data().product,
                                catogorie: doc.data().catogorie,
                                price: doc.data().price
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't share pictures of text. Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Oke thanks. I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the shop items with:

```
this.shopItem.push({
    product: doc.data().product,
    catogorie: doc.data().catogorie,
    price: doc.data().price
})
```

So they have three properties: `product`, `catogorie` [sic] and `price`. Since you're not adding an `id` property, your view returns `undefined` when you do `deleteItem(shopItems.id)` later.

So you'll want to add the document ID when you push the data to the `shopItem` array:

```
this.shopItem.push({
    id: doc.id,
    product: doc.data().product,
    catogorie: doc.data().catogorie,
    price: doc.data().price
})
```

Comment: Okee I get it now. That is why it wasn't working. Thanks for your your help.